# 'apply' function in R

Tags: r, apply, nan

I want to apply the following normalization function in 'R':
`normalize <- function(x) {return ((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))}`

However, my dataset has 68 observations and 960 variables, and some *NaN* here and there.
Of course, before applying the function I would like to remove these *NaNs*

So, I used the following function:
`df_normalized <- apply(df, 1, normalize, na.rm=TRUE)`

However, the `na.rm=TRUE` function is not being recognized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options  -

1. Change the `normalize` function to ignore the `NA` values in `max`, `min` functions.

```
normalize <- function(x) {
  (x - min(x, na.rm = TRUE)) / (max(x, na.rm = TRUE) - min(x, na.rm = TRUE))
}
```

2. Without changing the `normalize` function pass only non-NA values

```
df_normalized <- apply(df, 1, function(x) normalize(na.omit(x)))
```

Comment: Or include an `na.rm` argument to the `normalize` function that gets passed to each `max` and `min` call. Then the OPs `apply` call will work as written.